# System.FormatException: 'Index (zero based) >=0 and < size of the argument list.'

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have a code in vb.net as show below:

```
 Protected Sub gvQPRList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvQPRList.Load
        'If Not Session("SurveyID") Is Nothing Then
        'If Session("SurveyID").ToString <> "" Then
        '  If hfSurveyID.Value = "" Then
        If gvQPRList.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("Flags")
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("Criterion")
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("rpt_Dimensions")
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("InstrumentType")
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(4).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("level")
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(5).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("DueDate")
            gvQPRList.HeaderRow.Cells(6).Text = Me.Master.gm.GetLabel("ConditionStatus")
        End If
        'End If
        'End If
        ' End If
    End Sub
```

The above code is throwing the following exception at line  `If gvQPRList.Rows.Count <> 0 Then`

```
System.FormatException: 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'
```

I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the code above in order to get rid of this exception.

Comment: Why would you need to be testing the number of rows in the grid in the `Load` event handler? The form hasn't even been loaded at that point so how can the grid have rows?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I haven't touch the code. After removing certain contents from the webpage, I am getting error at the line `If gvQPRList.Rows.Count <> 0 Then`

Comment: Why refer to me if you're not going to answer my question?